# Protect our Azure Web App with a certificate

Tags: azure

We have a WebApp and we have registered a certificated in Azure Portal. We want that the webapp can only be called if the correct certificated is passed. Adding the certificate does not protect the webapp and all call are passed.
How can be protect our webapp such that it required that a certificated is passed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have inbound client certificates to pass the webserver you have to enable TLS Mutual Authentication for your Web App.

This is very nicely described in https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-web-configure-tls-mutual-auth/

First you have to run a script to change the default setting for passing client certificates. Than you can access the passed certificate and apply your access rules on it.